# Does GCP Cloud Armor support TCP load balancer? I am unable to add TCP load balancer as a Target in Cloud Armor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

In the GCP cloud armor documentation, it is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/managed-protection-overview?authuser=4&_ga=2.35955816.-958500654.1600324886&_gac=1.91214568.1604408592.Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmLevDI2fhN0THMDP1nI4Y3Mz-yc2zE-1MgS0iKyVNuJO6xabx18WoUaAiIpEALw_wcB#standard_tier_versus_plus_tier) that it supports HTTP(S) and TCP load balancers to be configured. But I am unable to add TCP load balancer as a Target in Cloud Armor as it doesn't show the TCP load balancer in the target list.

Answer (score 1):

Accoridng to Google document you attached, It is DDOS attack protection service that HTTP(S) and TCP load balancers are supported.

As your mention that "add TCP load balancer as a target in cloud armor", You may have tried create security policy.

But security policy service is not supported to TCP load balancer as a target yet.

Refer to Google document that describes Cloud armor's security policy requirements [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview?authuser=4#requirements)